# Django Rest Framework: How to copy a field from a related object on save?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm making a REST API to track characters for the Pathfinder Roleplaying game, and I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how to apply attributes from a Race to a Character.

In my app, a `Character` has fields for all of the attributes they can have. Some will be informed by their `Race`, others by their `Class`, etc.  For simplicity, I'll just focus on the `speed` attribute, since this copying behavior will be used in many places. So to reiterate:

All `Character` objects have a `speed` and a `race` field.  Every `Race` also has a `speed` attribute, and Races are pre-populated.  When a user creates a `Character`, they will choose a `Race` for their character, and the `Character`'s speed will be informed by the `Race`'s speed. I want this to happen when the `Character` model is saved - that is to say that sometime between when the user submits the request and the response 200 OK is sent, the value for the speed attribute will be copied from the selected `Race` object to the `Character` object.

Note, I'm not just relating the `Character`'s `speed` field because it can be altered by many different things, so I'll just update the value as modifiers are applied.

I'm mainly just looking for a point in the right direction right now, but any additional information would be helpful.

Edit:
models.py:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Character(models.Model):
    # character information
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    # Speed
    speed = models.IntegerField()

    # meta data
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='characters')

    # stringifier
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Race(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    speed = models.IntegerField()

    # stringifier
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from charman import models


class CharacterSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Character
        fields = ('url', 'speed', 'owner')


class RaceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    characters = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='character-detail', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Race
```

Comment: Can you include the code for your serializers (and models) in your question? Thanks.

Comment: sure. I'll remove extraneous stuff though, since they're pretty big.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a couple things about your models...

```
my_character.speed = my_charater.race.speed
my_character.save()
```

If you want that to happen when the Character is first saved...

```
# models.py
class Character(models.Model):
    [...]
    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        if self.id is None:
            # set default speed value
            self.speed = self.race.speed
        # either way, run the rest of your model's inherited save() behavior
        super(Character, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: That would make sense, but I don't know where to actually put that code.

Comment: Depends on when you want it to run. One place it might go is in the model's save() code, will add an example to the answer.

Comment: Great, I'll try that and let you know how it goes.

Comment: This worked, but the other answer suggests putting it in the serializer. I like that a bit more, but it's not working the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to do this on the serializer level, when the object is being created for the first time. Django REST framework provides the `post_save` hook that you can override to make this happen.

```
class CharacterSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Character
        fields = ('url', 'speed', 'owner')

    def post_save(self, obj, created=True):
        obj.speed = obj.race.speed
```

In Django REST framework 3, this hook has been renamed to `perform_create`.

Comment: I tried this (post_save and perform_create, I think I'm on version 3 though), but it didn't override what I had submitted in the request. I also tried omitting the speed field altogether, but then it complains that the field is required. I made it a ReadOnlyField in the serializer and now it complains about a `NOT NULL constraint` failure.

The other answer suggesting a save() method on the model seemed to work though. Why is that?

Comment: You might need to actually do it in pre_save (or before/during `serializer.save` in `perform_create`) then.

Comment: is it called pre_save in 3 as well? edit: I tried pre_save() and it also didn't overwrite.

Comment: It's [called `perform_create` in 3.0](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#generic-views). The code in your question uses `Field`, which was common in 2.x, so I assumed you were still on 2.x.